# MS Word Interop SaveAs2 loses Author names

Tags: c#, .net-core, office365, pdf-generation, office-interop

I have written a C# application using .Net Core 6, that manipulates Word documents using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word. These documents contain a field that shows the content of the document's Author property on the first page.
This property will often contain multiple names separated by commas, e.g.
John Smith, Jane Brown, etc.
However, when I attempt to save the Word document as PDF using SaveAs2, I find that the output PDF file contains only the name of the first author.

Typical code would be
`m_document.SaveAs2(destPath, FileFormat: WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF);`
although I see the same results using
`m_document.ExportAsFixedFormat(destPath, WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);`

My C# application replaces an older VB6 application that performs exactly the same operation using
`WordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat2 Target, wdExportFormatPDF`
that correctly outputs all the author names, running on the same PC with the identical MS Office installation (Microsoft 365, Version 2306)

How can I modify my C# code to do the same thing as the VB6 code has managed for the past 20 years?